# PHP Basics: Global variables & references

Tags: php, global-variables, pass-by-reference

I'm not sure what I'm missing here; I'm trying to understand fundamentals.

The goal is to build a function that starts with the string `Smith`, turns it lowercase into `smith` then reverses it into `htims`. Then use the built-in `str_repeat()` function to print it 10x in a vertical column like such:

```
htims
htims
htims
htims
...
x10
```

This is what I got:

```
01 function reverseString(&$lname)
02 {
03   $lname = "Smith"; // Starting off with Smith
04   $lname = strtolower($lname); // Lowercases Smith into smith
05   return strrev($lname); // Reverses smith into htims
06 }
07 
08 echo reverseString($lname); // Testing my function = success. Prints htims.
09 echo "\n \n"; // Added line break. Now to try to use a built-in function to print it 10x..
10 echo str_repeat(reverseString($lname), 10); // Prints htimshtimshtimshtimsh .. x10
```

So far so good.

Now **I want to add a line break between the repeated strings** so instead of printing `htimshtimshtimshtimsh` .. x10 it prints:

```
htims
htims
htims
...
x10
```

**This is where I got stuck.**

#### Attempt #1

I can't concatenate in the functions parameters:

```
echo str_repeat(reverseString($lname . "\n"), 10); // Does not print. Fine, I'm assuming it's not appropriate syntax.
```

#### Attempt #2

I can't reassign `$lname` a value outside of the function before the last echo:

```
10 $lname = $lname . "\n";
11 echo str_repeat(reverseString($lname), 10); // Does not print. Assuming because the variable does not have global scope.
```

#### Attempt #3

So I tried making `$lname` a global variable in the function before anything else:

```
01 function reverseString(&$lname)
02 {
03   global $lname; // Tried giving $lname global scope
04   $lname = "Smith";
05   $lname = strtolower($lname);
06   return strrev($lname);
07 }

...

10 $lname = $lname . "\n"; // But reassignment outside of the function STILL does not work.
11 echo str_repeat(reverseString($lname), 10); // Does not print.
```

#### Last ditch effort attempt #4

I tried giving global scope outside of the function for good measure. Did not work either:

```
01 function reverseString(&$lname)
02 {
04   $lname = "Smith";
05   $lname = strtolower($lname);
06   return strrev($lname);
07 }
08
09   global $lname; // Tried giving $lname global scope
```

#### Workaround

Adding the line breaks in the function works but I have to place them before my strings since eventually it will be reversed:

```
01 function reverseString(&$lname)
02 {
03   $lname = "\nSmith"; // Option 1
04   $lname = strtolower("\n" . $lname); // Option 2
05   return strrev("\n" . $lname); // Option 3
06 }
```

What I want to know is **why trying to make `$lname` a global variable and reassigning it a new value did not work** any way I tried.

Comment: Why make the param mutable with `&` here `(&$lname)` if you are returning a value anyway?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add the new line after getting the value back from the function....

```
echo str_repeat(reverseString($lname) . "\n", 10);
```

Comment: Any idea what I may be missing with the global variables?

Comment: It's more about when the value gets added.  If you add it as part of the parameter, then it will also be processed - and treated as part of the string to reverse.